# Wrangling clusters/centers of kmeans back into original data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

Here's some data.

```
df <- data.frame(groupvar=rep(c('a','b'),100),v1=rnorm(200),v2=rnorm(200))
```

Now I do k means within each group:

```
require(dplyr)

kobjs = df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>%
  do(kclust = kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5))
```

"kobjs" looks like this:

```
  groupvar      kclust
    (fctr)       (chr)
1        a <S3:kmeans>
2        b <S3:kmeans>
```

I'd like to grab the cluster assignment (and, ideally, the center points) and append them to the original data frame. I thought you could use broom to do this:

```
require(broom)
merged = kobjs %>%
  group_by(groupvar) %>% do(augment(.$kclust[[1]],df))
```

But that somehow yields a 400X4 matrix instead of a 200X4. How did that happen? How do I get the behavior I want?

EDIT1: Solved the way I wanted it, with some insight from aosmith. There's probably a way to make it more elegant (is the left_join necessary?) but it's the behavior I want:

```
kobjs = df %>%
  do(kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5) %>%
       fitted(method="centers") %>% 
       data.frame(cluster=rownames(.),entry=1:length(.),row.names=NULL)) %>%
  left_join(df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>% mutate(entry=1:n()),
            by=c("entry","groupvar"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you are using `augment` on the entire `df` rather than using just the subset for each group.  This is why you are getting a dataset that's twice as long as you expected.

So you'd need to do something like the following using `kobjs`.  I set the seed to 16 before making `kobjs`.

```
kobjs %>%
    group_by(groupvar) %>% 
    do(augment(.$kclust[[1]], df[df$groupvar == .$groupvar,]))

Source: local data frame [200 x 5]
Groups: groupvar [2]

   .rownames groupvar          v1         v2 .cluster
       (chr)   (fctr)       (dbl)      (dbl)   (fctr)
1          1        a  0.30291472  0.2203811        1
2          3        a -0.51381305  0.1480162        1
3          5        a -0.75246517 -0.6407782        2
4          7        a  0.06453416  1.2965984        3
5          9        a -0.62353541 -1.3240648        2
6         11        a  0.18435121 -1.0513837        5
7         13        a -0.26481666  2.8117979        4
8         15        a  0.56643441  0.1434451        1
9         17        a -0.30406035 -0.1477244        1
10        19        a  1.62538120 -0.5972593        5
..       ...      ...         ...        ...      ...
```

To get something more like what you want.

You do have other options.  For example, you could use `augment` in the original `do` step:

```
set.seed(16)
df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>%
    do(augment(kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5), .))

Source: local data frame [200 x 4]
Groups: groupvar [2]

   groupvar          v1         v2 .cluster
     (fctr)       (dbl)      (dbl)   (fctr)
1         a  0.30291472  0.2203811        1
2         a -0.51381305  0.1480162        1
3         a -0.75246517 -0.6407782        2
4         a  0.06453416  1.2965984        3
5         a -0.62353541 -1.3240648        2
6         a  0.18435121 -1.0513837        5
7         a -0.26481666  2.8117979        4
8         a  0.56643441  0.1434451        1
9         a -0.30406035 -0.1477244        1
10        a  1.62538120 -0.5972593        5
..      ...         ...        ...      ...
```

You could also pull out the `cluster` from the `kmeans` object and add these to the dataset with the following `do` coding.  This doesn't use *broom*, though.

```
set.seed(16)
df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>%
    do(data.frame(., kclust = kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5)$cluster))

Source: local data frame [200 x 4]
Groups: groupvar [2]

   groupvar          v1         v2 kclust
     (fctr)       (dbl)      (dbl)  (int)
1         a  0.30291472  0.2203811      1
2         a -0.51381305  0.1480162      1
3         a -0.75246517 -0.6407782      2
4         a  0.06453416  1.2965984      3
5         a -0.62353541 -1.3240648      2
6         a  0.18435121 -1.0513837      5
7         a -0.26481666  2.8117979      4
8         a  0.56643441  0.1434451      1
9         a -0.30406035 -0.1477244      1
10        a  1.62538120 -0.5972593      5
..      ...         ...        ...    ...
```

**Edit** to add example of saving two things from a model in a single `do` call.

You can fit and name model object in `do` and then pull multiple summary values from it, but it involves the use of curly brackets (I'm not sure if they are included in your irrational fear of square brackets ;-) ).

Here are two ways, first creating `model`, pulling out the fitted values as `fit`, and binding it all together with the original dataset (that's what the first `.` in `data.frame` represents).

```
df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>%
    do( { 
        model = kmeans(cbind(.$v1, .$v2), centers = 5)
        fit = fitted(model, methods = "centers")
        data.frame(., fit, cluster = rownames(fit), row.names = NULL) 
    })
```

I don't always like doing lots of naming, so the second option just works directly on `model` and skips the `fit` step.

```
df %>% group_by(groupvar) %>%
    do( { 
        model = kmeans(cbind(.$v1, .$v2), centers = 5)
        data.frame(., fitted(model, methods = "centers"), cluster = model$cluster, row.names = NULL) 
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. The first example is the behavior I was looking for. I like the other two ways to do it (I have an irrational fear of square brackets I guess), but the problem is that I don't know how to grab both the cluster assignment and the center in the same kmeans call. E.g.:

do(data.frame(., kclust = kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5)$cluster, kcenter = fitted(kmeans(cbind(.$v1,.$v2),centers=5))

is two kmeans calls instead of one. Any way to grab both with the same call?

Comment: Never mind, I think I figured it out - see edit in original post.

Comment: @NicholasRoot I added an edit to show some alternatives for how to fit a model and pull things out of it within a single `do` call (without fitting it multiple times).